# Division operator is not producing any results

Tags: tcl

I ran into problem in TCL. I can add and multiply two integer variables. This works just fine:

```
set hdsuc [expr {$hdsuccess * $hdcount}]
set hdsuc [expr {$hdsuccess + $hdcount}]
```

But, for some reason, I am not able to divide them. Following does not work at all:

```
set hdsuc [expr {$hdsuccess / $hdcount}]
```

The above returns 0. Could there some issue with the settings?

Comment: I'd guess that you're doing integer division, compare `expr { 1 / 2 }` and `expr { 1.0 / 2 }`. I don't know enough TCL to know what the "right" solution is though, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's doing integer division. You need to convert one of the arguments to a double. e.g.:

```
 set hdsuc [expr {double($hdsuccess) / $hdcount}]
```

Comment: +1 despite the use of the word “cast”. It's not a cast, it's a conversion. :-)